# How to send POST request to https using \Drupal::httpClient()?

Tags: 8

I want to send POST request to https using \Drupal::httpClient().
But ended up with error like

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate
>   problem: self signed certificate (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Below is my code.

```
$post_fields['name'] = 'aa';
    $fields_string = json_encode($post_fields);    
    $response = \Drupal::httpClient()
           ->post("https://localhost/example/api/user-update?_format=json", [
         'auth' => ['admin', 'admin'],
         'body' => $fields_string,
    'http_errors' => FALSE,
         'headers' => [
           'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
       ]);
    dsm($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

How to send POST request with \Drupal::httpClient().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message should inform you what is going on. You are using a self-signed certificate locally. This probably won't be an issue on your production sites, but this is not really useful for local development.

Inspect the `\Drupal::httpClient()` static method you may discover that it uses the `http_client_factory:fromOptions` service. Use this directly allows you to pass options into Guzzle to allow requests to sites using self-signed certificates.

```
$clientFactory = \Drupal::service('http_client_factory');
$client = $clientFactory->fromOptions(['verify' => FALSE]);
```

Obviously this is not ideal. You should probably parameterize the URL that you are using instead of hard coding the URL. Then locally you can test without a self-signed cert or HTTPS. Or parameterize the options you pass into Guzzle so that `verify => TRUE` when you're on production. It is **not** recommended to set it to FALSE and this is a security risk.

Answer (score 10):

We must pass the post values in http_client via **form_params**  . Here down is one of my code to make **OAuth2 authentication** to another drupal 8 REST api being used **simple_oauth** module.

```
$response = \Drupal::httpClient()->post($base_url . '/oauth/token', [
      'verify' => true,
      'form_params' => ['grant_type'=> 'password',
                        'client_id' => 'CLIENT-ID',
                        'client_secret'=> 'CLIENT-SECRET',
                        'scope'=>'',
                        'username'=>'admin',
                        'password'=>'admin',],
        'headers' => [
          'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ],
    ])->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: If anyone is having any problems with any code in the answers, you need to change "form_params" to just "json", that may work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

$client = $clientFactory->fromOptions(['verify' => FALSE]); make me have an error.

I tried this line above, which is working :

```
$response = $client->request($methode, $url->toString(), ['form_params' => $options, 'verify' => false]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get some idea from this doc
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/3-post-for-creating-content-entities

Answer (score 0):

I tried the various answers above, none did quite work. As it happens there was, in our case, a simpler solution.
We have several environments identified via $settings['environment'] in settings.php. One of those, "local", needs to work with self-signed certs. To avoid Guzzle/curl from complaining we do:

```
if ($environment == 'local') $params['verify'] = FALSE; // $params of course holds other needed bits for the call to happen...

$response = json_decode(Drupal::httpClient()
      ->post($target_url, $params)
      ->getBody()
      ->getContents());
```

Hope it helps.